# How to hide/remove search field in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

The store is running in: Magento ver. 1.4.1.1

Because the search is not working, we're wanting to hide the search bar until I have time to look into the problem. I've searched everywhere. I keep seeing people editing catalogsearch.xml but I don't even know where to find that.

To me it looks like the search field is contained in a content block (under or above the left navvy) which also has contact information. But I don't even know where that content block is.

==== EDIT ====
(Since I can't answer my OWN post for another 5 hours, here's the answer below:)

Found it:

Location: app > design > frontend > default > calshrm > template > catalogsearch > form.mini.phtml
Just removed the code and stored the removed section as a .txt file in the same directory.

Code removed:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
        <div class="dfsboxleft">
            <label for="search"><!--?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?--></label>
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="dfsbutton">
                <span>
                    <span><!--?php echo $this->__('Search') ?--></span>
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="dfsbox">
            <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryParamName() ?>"
                            value="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="dfsinput" />
            <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                    var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Product Search') ?>');
                    searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
            //]]>
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I'm assuming form.mini is something different than what is normal, in which case you may have to look for the file mentioned above, which I'm not sure where that one is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to app/design/frontend/[your interface]/[your theme]/template/page/html/header.phtml and remove:

**getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>**

You can also disable the module in **System->Configuration->Advanced->Disable Modules Output :: Mage_CatalogSearch**.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the search with the layout xml. You can use local.xml in
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/default/layout/local.xml

Put this in to hide the search:

```
<layout>
  <default>
    <reference name="header">
        <remove name="top.search" />
    </reference>
 </default> </layout>
```

With the local.xml file you have a central point in your theme to change the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using chrome (right clicking on the serch box, and clicking inspect element) to look at the code. You could hide the input id "search" with a name "q" using jquery. It should be more simple than finding the blocks in xml.

It's not really the best solution, since refreshing the page may show it for a second (depending on the speed of the site), but it should be temporary and you're better off spending the time fixing the search IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about doing something similar with css using display:none. But finally figured it out.